# Finding upper critical value with Chebyshev's inequality

Tags: probability, statistics, inequality, poisson-distribution, hypothesis-testing

Consider $X$ is a Poisson random variable with distribution $X$~$Pois(\theta)$. 
I define the mean in my hypothesis as $\lambda$ and nominal significance level $\alpha$.

Null hypothesis  $H_0 : \lambda=\theta $

Alternative hypothesis $H_1 : \lambda>\theta$

Reject $H_0$ if $P(X\geq \theta_u )\leq \alpha$

I'm trying to find $\theta_u$ using Chebyshev's inequality.

**Here is my approach:**
According to Chebyshev's inequality $P(|X-\theta|\geq k\sqrt \theta)\leq \frac{1}{k^2}$

Since $X\geq \theta_u>\theta$ ,  $|X-\theta|=(X-\theta)$

So $P((X-\theta)\geq k\sqrt \theta)\leq \frac{1}{k^2}$

$P(X\geq \theta + k\sqrt \theta)\leq \frac{1}{k^2}$

Let's assume $\theta_u=\theta + k\sqrt \theta$

So, $k=\frac{\theta_u-\theta}{\sqrt \theta}$,

If $\alpha=\frac{1}{k^2}$ then $\theta_u=\theta + \sqrt\frac{\theta}{\alpha}$; Is it correct?

**Direct approach:** 
$P(X\geq \theta_u)=e^\theta\sum_{k=\theta_u}^{\infty}\frac{\theta^k}{k!}\leq \alpha$

I believe it's not possible to find a solution for $\theta_u$ through direct approach.

What is the best way to find a simplified (which can be computed easily) expression for $\theta_u$ ?

Comment: Why don´t you use the CLT ?

Comment: According to CLT $\theta_u=\theta + \sqrt \theta$ which is same as in Chebyshev inequality approach if $\alpha=1$ but $\alpha$ should be less than $\theta$ since $k$ is less than 1. I am confused here.

Comment: First of all you have to substract something, if you want the value of the lower bound. If you have normally distributed variables, the lower bound is $\mu - z_{(1-\frac{\alpha}{2})}\cdot \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt n}$. Therefore an approximated confidence interval for poisson distributed variables is  $\theta_u=\theta - z_{(1-\frac{\alpha}{2})}\cdot \sqrt{\frac{\theta}{ n}}$
$.\quad z_{(1-\frac{\alpha}{2})}$ is the z-value of the Standard normal distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chebyshev's Inequality is useful in proofs, but it applies to any
distribution with a mean and variance, so it does not give 
a very sharp bound for such purposes as getting a CI. If this is
a drill problem on use of Chebyshev's Inequality, then OK.
But if you want a CI for the Poisson mean that has anywhere
near it's advertised coverage probability, this is not a good procedure.

First, let's make it clear we have a sample of "size 1."
This not a severe restriction because if we had 10 iid observations,
then their sum would again be Poisson. So the $\lambda$ we wish
to estimate is for a single (perhaps combined) observation.

Suppose our observation is $X \sim Pois(\lambda)$ with $\lambda$
unknown. If $X$ is reasonably large, then a good 95% CI is
$X + 2 \pm 1.96\sqrt{X+1}.$

Another method is to make a frequentist CI using a Bayesian
argument with an "improper" gamma prior. It requires software
to compute. A statement in R that gives a 95% CI is
  `qgamma(c(.025,.975), x, 1)`. This method works well
for confidence levels other than 95%.

For example, if $X = 24$, then the first method gives
$26 \pm 1.96\sqrt{25}$ or $(16.2, 35.8).$
and the second gives $(16.18, 35.71).$ A simulation with
a million values of $X$ from $Pois(24)$ showed that
95% of CIs generated by each method actually contained $\lambda=24$
very nearly 95% of the time.

If $X = 8$, then the first gives $( 4.12, 15.88)$, and
the second $(3.45, 14.42).$  Here I would prefer the
second interval because of the relatively small value of $X$.

If $X$ is the sum of $n = 10\,$ observations, then divide
the endpoints of the above CIs by 10, to get a CI for
the per-observation rate $\lambda/10$.

Notes: (1) Wikipedia on 'Poisson' has CI based on
the chi-squared distribution. (2) 'Exact' CIs based
on the likelihood ratio are a little difficult to
compute. One problem is that the Poisson distribution
is discrete, so that it is difficult to apportion
exactly 2.5% in each tail of the distribution.
(3) One sometimes sees the CI $X \pm 1.96\sqrt{X}$
recommended. This method has been shown to give
relatively poor results. For $\lambda = 24$, its
coverage probability was only about 93%.